# React Native responsive vs React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi all so i come from react native background(not professional) and i wanna ask something about responsiveness.

In react native apps i never used something like media querys etc.

I used per centage(%) in all my layouts-images-font sizes etc .

Why i can't use this in react js projects?

for example ,when i try to put hight with per centage (%) it never accepts it(im forced to used rems,ems,px destroying my dreams about responsiveness without media querys:P ) ,but in width it does,why is that ?

Thanks in advance.